# Least square Equilibrium Solution (ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, reference-request

I've recently encountered a problem stated as follows:

> Given that $z\in C([0,+\infty))$ and $a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{R}$, find the least square equilibrium solution of the ODE system:
>   $$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x'=x+2y+z-a_1,\ t>0\\y'=x+2y+2z-a_2,\ t>0\end{array}\right.$$
>   if it is known that $y(t)=-z(t)$.

So, I made the following thoughts:

1. Plug in the extra condition, so the system may be written, in matrix form, as:
   $$\mathbb{x}'=\underbrace{\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\\1 & 0\end{array}\right)}_{C}\mathbb{x}+\underbrace{\left(\begin{array}{c}-a_1\\-a_2\end{array}\right)}_{b},$$
   where $\mathbf{x}=(x,y)^t$.
2. At first, solve the homogenous system in the usual way (one may also observe that this system is easy to convert to a second order equation, however I thought solving the system would be easier). The general solution is:
   $$\psi(t)=c_1\lambda_1e^{\lambda_1t}(\lambda_1,1)^t+c_2\lambda_1e^{\lambda_2t}(\lambda_2,1)^t,$$
   where $\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{1\mp\sqrt{5}}{2}$, respectively. So, one of the system's fundamental matrix is:
   $$\Phi(t)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}\lambda_1e^{\lambda_1t} & \lambda_2e^{\lambda_2t}\\e^{\lambda_1t} & e^{\lambda_2t}\end{array}\right).$$
   No, for the non-homogeneous equation, if $\mathbf{y}(t_0)=\mathbf{y}_0$, $_0\geq0$, is some initial condition, then the solution has the general form:
   $$\mathbf{x}(t)=G(t,t_0)\int_{t_0}^tG(t,s)b(s)ds,$$
   where $G(t,t_0)$ is the state transition matrix:
   $$G(t,t_0)=\Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(t_0).$$
3. Since this is the soluion of the homogenous, $\lVert L\mathbf{x}-b\rVert_2^2=0$, so the soluion above has minimal square error ($L$ is the linear operator $Lu=u'-Cu$ which describes the system).

At this point it is where I am confused, because, if this was he appropriate way to tackle the question, why not request to simply solve the systme instead of searching for a minimum equilibrium solution?

So, to conclude, my question is: **Is this the right way to deal with this problem or have I misunderstood somehing regarding least square error in ODE systems? If the case is the latter, what is this misconception (reference to other works to study is welcome)**.

Comment: The question does not make sense, as there is exactly one equilibrium point. And least squares of what? Some vector, some function, some vector valued function? What is the overdetermined linear system of equations?

Comment: There was a typo derivative missing) in the first equation. Also, I suppose that what it is implied is the minimizer of some $L_2$ norm or so, however, being able to explicitly solve the system makes this (to my eyes) needless. Moreover, the presence of the term "equilibrium" is also not clear to me. However, this is the way the question is posed.

Comment: @LutzL I also had another thought that seemed to lead to nowhere, which was to mimic the usual "tricks" of the least squares method in the finite case. That is, if $L$ is the operator describing he problem, let $L^*$ be its adjoint and then manipulate the $\lVert Lx-b\rVert_2^2$ so as to arrive to an equation of the form $L^*Lx=L^*b$. However, this needs $L$ to be bouned, which is not the case, while shifting to an integral form of the system seems useless results, since the problem is defined over $[0,+\infty)$, which is not compact.

Comment: For what it is worth, I also do not understand what the problem is aiming for here.